# Create the contact in XDB without Session.Abandon and save Engagement, behavior ,Interaction facets

Tags: xdb, xconnect, contact-facets, goals

What would be the best practice to save the Contact in XDB,

At present if "Contact" not exists in XDB (validating by phone + email) and it submit the "Contact-us-Form" then I am using

```
 Session.Abandon() 
 Session.IdentifyAs(phone,email)
```

method to save contact in XDB.(my code :- https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/23830/1338)

By doing this I can see below facets and the goals (goal attached with Form) attached to contact in XDB + Experience Profile.

[image]

but
if i not use

```
Session.Abandon()
```

and use only

```
Session.IdentifyAs(phone,email)
```

Then I am not able to get goals , interaction, engagement facets  in XDB + EP (see below pic) 
But If I resubmit the form with new Phone and Email then these current(last)goals , interaction, engagement facets attaching to new Contact Profile

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your forms are in AJAX mode, your issue is going to be that tracker is configured to not run on Forms Ajax mode. Not sure why.

At the top of your code, add this.

```
if (Tracker.Current == null && Tracker.Enabled)
{
   Tracker.StartTracking();
}
```

Then do your normal xConnect code

```
var firstNameField = GetFieldById(data.FirstNameFieldId, formSubmitContext.Fields);
var lastNameField = GetFieldById(data.LastNameFieldId, formSubmitContext.Fields);
var emailField = GetFieldById(data.EmailFieldId, formSubmitContext.Fields);
if (firstNameField == null && lastNameField == null && emailField == null)
{
    return false;
}

XdbContactService.IdentifyByEmailOrAddIdentifier(GetValue(emailField));

var contactReference = this.contactIdentificationRepository.GetContactReference();

using (var client = this.contactIdentificationRepository.CreateContext())
{

    var contact = client.Get(contactReference, new ContactExpandOptions(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey));
    if (contact == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contact));
    }

    var personalInformation = contact.GetFacet<PersonalInformation>(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey) ?? new PersonalInformation();
    contactFacetsProvider.SetContactInfo(GetValue(firstNameField), GetValue(lastNameField), personalInformation);

    contactFacetsProvider.SetPreferredEmail(GetValue(emailField), contact, client);

    client.Submit();
    contactFacetsProvider.UpdateTracker();
}
```

You can find the contactIdentificationRepository [here](https://gist.github.com/dnstommy/d4e92c46b4878f70cb1f570439bd68c8)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done:

```
private readonly string IdentifierSource = "Subcribe.Form";
protected virtual ITracker CurrentTracker => Tracker.Current;

protected override bool Execute(XYZ data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
        {
            if (CurrentTracker == null && Tracker.Enabled)
            {
                Tracker.StartTracking();
            }
            var manager = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as ContactManager;
            if (manager != null)
            {

                using (var client = this.CreateClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var firstName = GetFieldById(data.FirstNameFieldId, formSubmitContext.Fields);
                        var lastName = GetFieldById(data.LastNameFieldId, formSubmitContext.Fields);
                        var email = GetFieldById(data.EmailFieldId, formSubmitContext.Fields);
                        var mobile = GetFieldById(data.MobileFieldId, formSubmitContext.Fields);

                        var fName = GetValue(firstName);
                        var lName = GetValue(lastName);
                        var emailValue = GetValue(email);

                        string identifier = emailValue.ToLower().Trim();
                        var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference(IdentifierSource, identifier);

                        XConnect.Contact contact = client.Get(trackerIdentifier,
                        new ContactExpandOptions(CollectionModel.FacetKeys.PersonalInformation, CollectionModel.FacetKeys.EmailAddressList, PhoneNumberList.DefaultFacetKey));
                        if (contact != null)
                        {
                            SetPersonalInformation(GetValue(firstName), GetValue(lastName), contact, client);
                            SetEmail(GetValue(email), contact, client);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            XConnect.Contact newContact = null;
                            if (CurrentTracker.Contact.IsNew)
                            {
                                CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
                                manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(CurrentTracker.Contact);
                                CurrentTracker.Session.IdentifyAs(IdentifierSource, identifier);
                                newContact = client.Get(trackerIdentifier, new ContactExpandOptions());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var anyIdentifier = CurrentTracker.Contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault();
                                Sitecore.XConnect.Contact existingContact = client.Get(new IdentifiedContactReference(anyIdentifier.Source, anyIdentifier.Identifier),
                       new ContactExpandOptions(CollectionModel.FacetKeys.PersonalInformation, CollectionModel.FacetKeys.EmailAddressList,  PhoneNumberList.DefaultFacetKey));
                                if (existingContact.IsKnown)
                                {
                                    CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
                                    manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(CurrentTracker.Contact);
                                    CurrentTracker.Session.IdentifyAs(IdentifierSource, identifier);
                                    newContact = client.Get(trackerIdentifier, new ContactExpandOptions());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    CurrentTracker.Session.IdentifyAs(IdentifierSource, identifier);
                                    newContact = client.Get(trackerIdentifier, new ContactExpandOptions());
                                }
                            }
                            if (newContact != null)
                            {
                                SetPersonalInformation(GetValue(firstName), GetValue(lastName), newContact, client);
                                SetEmail(GetValue(email), newContact, client);


                            }
                        }

                        client.Submit();
                        manager.RemoveFromSession(CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactId);
                        CurrentTracker.Session.Contact = manager.LoadContact(CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactId);
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex + ex.StackTrace);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```